# script with print screen and task scheduler problems

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, command-line, scheduled-tasks

On a production system a script opens screens and sends them to hypersnapDX. Hypersnap then saves a picture in a folder which then is copied onto a server.

This script is done by a cmd script. The whole system was updated from Windows XP (I think it was XP) to Windows 7 a while ago. The script didnt work anymore.

Now I found out the script works fine if it is started manually by the user, simply by double clicking the .bat file. If it is started by a task it does not work.

To me that means the problem is the task scheduler.

Question:

Does starting a script via task scheduler give a different display manager to a program somehow? Because the script does exactly that: print screen and save as picture.

Is there a way to start the .bat file via task scheduler, but not opening the .bat but somehow execute the commands by task scheduler itself?

Is it possible to execute the .bat via task scheduler but starting it minimized? I already created a shortcut with a minimize option but task scheduler links automatically to the .bat file ignoring the shortcut and therefore the minimize option.

Comment: Have a look over here to give you and example of what you can do http://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window